# Git push / commit dates in Xcode

Tags: git, xcode5

Let me briefly explain the issue:
There are three mac machines M1, M2, M3.
M3 is hosting git repositories. There is an xcodeproj repository on M3 which is being worked on from both m1 and M2 and pushed / committed to M3.
now the problem is suppose on M1 user changes system date to some past date and performs a commit of its work. M2 takes an update from within XCode's source control menu and project is in updated state on M2 now.
But if one select Source Control > History to see the changes done by M1 then it will not be visible in today's date since M1 had made changes in past date.
I would like to know if there is a way in XCode to force the date to be taken of the repository server [M3 here ] and not what date is on the machine doing the commit. I want to apply a general solution and not want to rebase or temporary fix to it.

Answer (score 0):

No.  That git is a *distributed* version control system means that it was designed to operate without a central server, so you cannot delegate to one for the time.  It was designed with the notion that peers are trusted (and if they're not, they should go through a code review before their changes are accepted, which gives you the opportunity to reject a commit and give the author a chance to rewrite it.)

You should use ntp on the clients.